# How could I display richtext in QTableView using QSortFilterProxyModel?

Tags: pyqt4, qtableview, richtext, qsortfilterproxymodel

## Presentation:

I have a table with 5 columns and a QLineEdit that acts like a filter for the second column. Also, I'm planing to implement a button to hide/show rows that match the text from the first column and another one to highlight text from the second one.

The five columns are:

1. Just icons, to each icon corresponds a name.
2. Hyperlink text that must act and look like a link (just like an HTML anchor inside a QLabel).
3. File sizes expressed in: KB, MB, GB, TB, etc. Must be hyperlinks like the second column.
4. Integers
5. Integers

All columns need to be sortable.

I was able to solve almost everything till the implementation of QSortFilterProxyModel.
This is what I have:

ResultsStandardItem.py (subclass of QStandardItem for custom sort):

```py
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import re

class ResultsStandardItem(QtGui.QStandardItem):
    def __init__(self, sortKey, sortType='string'):
        super(ResultsStandardItem, self).__init__()

        if sortType == 'size':
            suf = re.search('(KB|B|GB|MB|TB)$', sortKey).group(1)
            num = float(re.search('^[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?', sortKey).group())
            if suf == 'B':
                self.sortKey = num
            elif suf == 'KB':
                self.sortKey = num * 1024
            elif suf == 'MB':
                self.sortKey = num * 1024 * 1024
            elif suf == 'GB':
                self.sortKey = num * 1024 * 1024 * 1024
            elif suf == 'TB':
                self.sortKey = num * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024
        else:
            self.sortKey = sortKey

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.sortKey < other.sortKey
```

Main code:

```py
resultsMdl = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
resultsTbl = QtGui.QTableView(self)
resultsTbl.setModel(resultsMdl)
...
for i in range(len(site)):
    row = resultsMdl.rowCount()
    resultsMdl.insertRow(row)

    columnOneItem = ResultsStandardItem(str.lower(site[i]))
    columnOneItem.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('img/' + str.lower(site[i]) + '.png'))

    columnTwoItem = QtGui.QStandardItem()
    columnTwoItemLa = QtGui.QLabel('<a href="' + details[i] + '">' + file[i] + '</a>')
    columnTwoItemLa.setOpenExternalLinks(True)

    columnThreeItem = ResultsStandardItem(size[i], 'size')
    columnThreeItem.setData(size[i])
    columnThreeItemLa = QtGui.QLabel('<a href="' + download[i] + '">' + size[i] + '</a>')
    columnThreeItemLa.setOpenExternalLinks(True)

    columnFourItem = QtGui.QStandardItem()
    columnFourItem.setData(seeders[i], Qt.DisplayRole)

    columnFiveItem = QtGui.QStandardItem()
    columnFiveItem.setData(leechers[i], Qt.DisplayRole)

    resultsMdl.setItem(row, 0, columnOneItem)
    resultsMdl.setItem(row, 1, columnTwoItem)
    resultsTbl.setIndexWidget(columnTwoItem.index(), columnTwoItemLa)
    resultsMdl.setItem(row, 2, columnThreeItem)
    resultsTbl.setIndexWidget(columnThreeItem.index(), columnThreeItemLa)
    resultsMdl.setItem(row, 3, columnFourItem)
    resultsMdl.setItem(row, 4, columnFiveItem)

resultsTbl.setSortingEnabled(True)
```

Everything is working great. The first column displays only icons and is sortable, the second and third displays richtext and the custom sort works as expected. The only thing that should be solved, is the fact that the QLabel doesn't have Qt.TextElideMode, so, when the text doesn't fit in the column, it just get cut.

## Problem:

When I enable QSortFilterProxyModel, the QLabels disappear. So I have to display the text in the normal way and the custom sort stops working.
I'm stuck here, don't know where to go. Besides, I have to implement the highlighting and I don't know how. So I need to solve the first problem having in mind that the next step is the implementation of highlighting.

I'm new with Python and Qt, and need someone to explain me the right approach. I've been with this the last couple of days. I don't want to pick the first alternative and then go back because that approach doesn't let me implement the other stuff I need.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
I was able to use custom search setting "setSortRole(Qt.UserRole)".  And for every item, I set the data with the corresponding value that is going to be used to sort. Also, I changed the "ResultsStandardItem" to set data and not the sortKey.

ResultsStandardItem.py:

```py
...
else:
    self.sortKey = sortKey

self.setData(self.sortKey, Qt.UserRole)
```

Main:

```py
    columnThreeItem = ResultsStandardItem(size[i], 'size')
    columnThreeItem.setData(size[i], Qt.DisplayRole)
```

So, the richtext is the only thing missing.